# ASP.Net WindowsTokenRoleProvider not matching Domain Groups

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I am trying to use the default `ASPNetWindowsToken` provider to authorize users in an application that I am using Windows impersonation to log users in.  If I add a IsInRole to the code behind the page in the page load, I can see the user is in the proper roles, but when I add the authorization to the web.config, I am getting 401 unauthorized errors.  Not sure if I am missing something or not, but any help you can give would be appreciated.  Below is my web.config.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" />
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <authentication mode="Windows" />

    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow roles="DOMAIN\Group" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: What happens if you reverse the order of the allow and deny rules? I was under the impression that rules were executed in order, and the deny rule would preclude any further tests.